# how can i execute cfstoredproc using cfprocresult to return refcursor in railo server

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, coldfusion, railo

I have a software with 8k+ cfstoredprocs using cfprocresult and i am getting the error when i try to execute this code in railo server.

Code:

```
<cfstoredproc procedure="package_name.procedure_name" datasource="#dsn#">
    <cfprocresult name="qryEndereco">
</cfstoredproc>
```

Error:

> ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
>
> PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'procedure_name'
>
> ORA-06550: line 1, column 7: PL/SQL: Statement ignored

I can't change stored procedures, i need work in server configuration or something like that to solve this issue.

Comment: That second error message looks relevent.  What's your interpretation of it?

Answer (score 4):

The error tells you to provide the required arguments. Use [`cfprocparam`](https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/cfml-reference/coldfusion-tags/tags-p-q/cfprocparam.html) and nest them within `cfstoredproc`.

Example:

```
<cfstoredproc procedure="package_name.procedure_name" datasource="#dsn#">
    <cfprocparam type="IN" value="param1" cfSqlType="CF_SQL_VARCHAR">
    <cfprocparam type="IN" value="param2" cfSqlType="CF_SQL_VARCHAR">
    <cfprocresult name="qryEndereco">
</cfstoredproc>
```

The construct above is equivalent to the SQL statement:
`CALL package_name.procedure_name('param1', 'param2');`

Comment: your answer is ok but i needed work on fix without edit any code. Tks.

Answer (score 0):

I found the fix without change procedures.

I could not edit them cuz we have around 8k procedures do edit, so i just changed the drive in datasource to use macromedia.oracle driver and now its working without touch in code.

I dont know why but only macromedia driver work without an extra  (to out parameters)